# Make silverlight app on WP7 run full screen

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want my silverlight app to run in full screen (disabling the battery/signal bar up there)

I tried:

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.IsFullScreen = true;
```

But it doesn't work, how can I be able to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the SystemTray to invisible

xaml (in the page declaration):

```
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

code:

```
SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
```